# Printing the return address using format string

Tags: c, function, stack, return

I am required to print out the return address stored in the stack for a function?
The format I am supposed to follow to print it is

```
void function() 
{
      int *RetPtr = 0;
      printf("Return address 0x%08x\n",
                 (unsigned int *)(&RetPtr+Return_addr_Offset));
      /*Code goes here*/

}
```

Can someone please help! I am not supposed to be using inbuilt function.
How can I do this?

Comment: Isn't this specific to an architecture, processor type, and/or compiler?

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to print without printf, or how to calculate Return_addr_Offset?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to calculate Return_addr_Offset? I am reqd' to use printf function.......I am running it on Linux ubuntu 2.6.32-21-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: I am running it on Linux ubuntu 2.6.32-21-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: @Merlyn: Yes, as well as the compiler's optimization settings.

Answer (score 0):

This smells like homework to me if you can't use the built-in functions.

In any case, there's nothing magic about it being a pointer; you just need to print out a hex number.

Without knowing what functions if any you are allowed to use, it's kind of hard to help. You basically need to work out the eight hex digits then output them.

Comment: Any ideas how I can work out the eight hex digits? I was thinking if I declare a char array and assign it to the RetPtr and basically calculate the offset (some math) to the return address. and try to print that. It does not really work...

Answer (score 0):

You need to work out what `Return_addr_Offset` is supposed to be.  RetPtr is allocated on the stack, so by calculating some offset relative to RetPtr's address, you can print out the address of the calling function that was stored in the stack when it called into your function.  The actual value of offset you need depends on what computer architecture you're on and the calling convention.